# How do I truncate a PySpark dataframe of timestamp type to the day?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe that includes timestamps in a column (call the column 'dt'), like this:

```
2018-04-07 16:46:00
2018-03-06 22:18:00
```

When I execute:

```sql
SELECT trunc(dt, 'day') as day
```

...I expected:

```
2018-04-07 00:00:00
2018-03-06 00:00:00
```

But I got:

```
null
null
```

How do I truncate to the day instead of the hour?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You use wrong function. [`trunc` supports only a few formats](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.trunc.html):

> Returns date truncated to the unit specified by the format.

> :param format: 'year', 'yyyy', 'yy' or 'month', 'mon', 'mm'

Use [`date_trunc` instead](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc.html):

> Returns timestamp truncated to the unit specified by the format.

> :param format: 'year', 'yyyy', 'yy', 'month', 'mon', 'mm',
> 'day', 'dd', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'week', 'quarter'

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_trunc

df = spark.createDataFrame(["2018-04-07 23:33:21"], "string").toDF("dt").select(col("dt").cast("timestamp"))

df.select(date_trunc("day", "dt")).show()
# +-------------------+                                                           
# |date_trunc(day, dt)|
# +-------------------+
# |2018-04-07 00:00:00|
# +-------------------+
```

Comment: This works.  But I had to upgrade to Spark 2.3 to get it - it's new in that version.

Comment: One thing that tripped me up that's worth noting: the format field comes FIRST, the date comes SECOND. Otherwise you get all NULLs as in OP.

Comment: The above was helpful, helped me find this preferred code: <br> 
`from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, current_date` <br> 
`DF0 = spark.read.table("myLakeTable_ofActivity")` <br> 
`DF1 = DF0.filter(to_date(DF0.ACTIVITYDATE) == current_date())` <br> 
`DF2 = DF1.orderBy(DF1.ACTIVITYDATE.desc())` <br>
`DF2.show(100, truncate=False)`

Answer (score 1):

For spark <= 2.2.0

Please use this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import weekofyear, year, to_date, concat, lit, col
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.createDataFrame([['2020-10-03 05:00:00']], schema=['timestamp']) \
    .withColumn('timestamp', col('timestamp').astype(TimestampType())) \
    .withColumn('date', to_date('timestamp').astype(TimestampType())) \
    .show(truncate=False)

+-------------------+-------------------+
|timestamp          |date               |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2020-10-03 05:00:00|2020-10-03 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

For spark > 2.2.0 [datetime patterns in spark 3.0.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc, col
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.createDataFrame([['2020-10-03 05:00:00']], schema=['timestamp']) \
    .withColumn('timestamp', col('timestamp').astype(TimestampType())) \
    .withColumn('date', date_trunc(timestamp='timestamp', format='day')) \
    .show(truncate=False)

+-------------------+-------------------+
|timestamp          |date               |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2020-10-03 05:00:00|2020-10-03 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it with string manipulation:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, concat

df = df.withColumn('date', concat(df.date.substr(0, 10), lit(' 00:00:00')))
```