# How do I get the first date of the week from Date column in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a normal timestamp column in my PySpark dataframe. I want to get the starting date of the week from the given date in a new column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I truncate a PySpark dataframe of timestamp type to the day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947962/how-do-i-truncate-a-pyspark-dataframe-of-timestamp-type-to-the-day)

Comment: Use `date_trunc`

Answer (score 4):

For spark <= 2.2.0

Please use this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import weekofyear, year, to_date, concat, lit, col
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.createDataFrame([['2020-10-03 05:00:00']], schema=['timestamp']) \
    .withColumn('timestamp', col('timestamp').astype(TimestampType())) \
    .withColumn('week', weekofyear('timestamp')) \
    .withColumn('year', year('timestamp')) \
    .withColumn('date_of_the_week', to_date(concat('week', lit('/'), 'year'), "w/yyyy")) \
    .show(truncate=False)

+-------------------+----+----+----------------+
|timestamp          |week|year|date_of_the_week|
+-------------------+----+----+----------------+
|2020-10-03 05:00:00|40  |2020|2020-09-27      |
+-------------------+----+----+----------------+
```

For spark > 2.2.0

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc, col
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.createDataFrame([['2020-10-03 05:00:00']], schema=['timestamp']) \
    .withColumn('timestamp', col('timestamp').astype(TimestampType())) \
    .withColumn('date_of_the_week', date_trunc(timestamp='timestamp', format='week')) \
    .show(truncate=False)

+-------------------+-------------------+
|timestamp          |date_of_the_week   |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2020-10-03 05:00:00|2020-09-28 00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```